# Renaming files and keep specific pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to rename PDF's in a folder. Someone keeps sending them to me with different filenames. However, the last 1 or 2 digits are good. They should be the same.

- NK 2017 no 4.pdf
- NK pdf 2017 no. 5.pdf
- NK PDF 2016.09.09 no. 19.pdf
- NK 2016.08.26 no. 18.pdf

and so on. Only the last number should be kept,

- number4.pdf
- number5.pdf
- number19.pdf
- number18.pdf

I've tried to substitue the result from regex, but with no luck. The code works when i use something like sed  's/2017/foo/ '. But i need the pattern of the last number before .pdf in the result .. What's the error, what i'm doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/foo/bar/ -type f -iname "NK*" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f
do
  mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed 's/.+\([0-9]{1,3}\.pdf\)/number\1/'`";
done
```

Comment: if the files are in single folder, use `for f in NK*` instead of find+while... seems like using last field will do trick for you... `echo "$f" | awk '{print "number" $NF}'`... see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `mv` command to this:

```
mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.pdf\)/number\1/')"
```

Basic regex does not support the following:

- `.+` (use `.*` instead)
- `{m,n}` (use `\{m,n\}` instead)

Comment: Thanks, this one did the trick; however, takes only the last digit of the number before .pdf. Strange .. on https://regex101.com/ the expression *([0-9]{1,3}.pdf) takes also only the last digit (and not 2!)

Comment: @user165410 : I see there's always a space before the numbers, you can target that, i.e insert a space after `.*`

Comment: Sometimes there's a space .. :-/ The comment of @sundeep pointend at the usage of BRE/ERE for POSIX. There's no \D, so i used [^0-9] instead:


[code >]    mv "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's/.*[^0-9]\([0-9]\{1,2\}\.pdf\)/run4-number\1/')" [<code]


This is working for me.

Comment: @MatthijsG : Yes, that would be better. Edited my answer to include your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issues with your answer are you missed `$` on your variable and you are escaping parenthesis you need in your regular expression.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/foo/bar/ -type f -iname "NK*" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f
do
  mv "$f" "`echo $f | sed 's/.* ([0-9]{1,3}).pdf/number$1.pdf/'`";
done
```

The un-escaped parenthesis allows you to access groups in variable form. First set is `$1` and it increases from there by one.

Comment: you seem to be confusing `sed` regex with some other flavor like pcre... `sed` supports BRE/ERE

Comment: Using your command the cli returns mv: './file1' and './file1' are the same file